# Как правильно сделать меню на bootsrtap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Как мне правильно сделать такое меню?

[image: head-menu]

то, что у меня получилось с помощью bootsrtap на codepen:

```
codepen.io/asvis/pen/Ywexvw
```

но сами линии у меня не ровно стоят, а при ховере элементы в меню сдвигаются.

если нужны source'ы то вот ссылка: [source-header.zip](http://anyout.ru/source-header.zip)

Comment: спасибо за доп.информацию

Comment: Не понял, а какие линии "не ровно стоят"?

Comment: @cyadvert вот эти: http://prntscr.com/9trwbg на картинке они ровнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд у Вас там все очень наворочено. Слишком... Можно все сильно упростить. `div.row>div>a`- больше и не надо. Как мне кажется, там легче переписать, чем исправлять код.
Вообщем ниже я предлагаю свой вариант, который делает, как мне кажется, то, что Вам нужно.

Поскольку все элементы меню вобщем-то одинаковые, то я оформил лишь первые два "New Ad" и "New Folder". Остальные, думаю, по образу и подобию Вы сможете организовать сами.

```css
#head {
  text-align: center;
}
a.topLink {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: rgb(95, 95, 95);
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  line-height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}
#head>div:not(#logo):before {
  background-color: rgb(95, 95, 95);
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
#head a:hover:not(.logo_img) {
  background-color: rgb(104, 144, 231);
  color: white;
}
#head a:hover,
#head a:hover .glyphicon {
  color: white;
}
.header-box {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(18, 37, 74, 0.3);
  height: 75px;
}
.logo_img {
  background-image: url("http://papeo.braintips.ru/images/logo-head2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 33px;
  z-index: 131;
}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header-box">
  <div id="head" class="row">
    <div id="logo" class="col-xs-3">
      <a class="navbar-brand logo_img" href="/"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a class="topLink" href="#new_ads">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></div>New Ad</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a class="topLink" href="#new_folder">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></div>New Folder</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Некоторые замечания, важные для понимания этого решения.

- для того, чтобы сделать маленькие вертикальные линии, не обязательно делать отдельные `div`ы. Я предлагаю воспользоваться псевдоэлементом `:before` (или `:after` - как удобней).
  Обратите внимание на CSS `#head>div:not(#logo):before`.
  Перед каждым "ребенком" элемента `#head` (кроме `#logo`) добавляется
  блок с серым фоном шириной 2px  высотой 22px абсолютным
  позиционированием и отступом сверху в 35%. Все это дает возможность
  создать маленькую вертикальную линию и точно ее позиционировать
  относительно блока.
  Можете поиграть с показателями, чтобы сделать
  так, как Вам надо.
- сделав `a` тэги меню как `display: inline-block; width: 100%` можно избежать вот этой ужасной конструкции: `<div class="wellhead" onclick="location.href='#new_ads'"><a href="#new_ads">`
- добавив `line-height: 75px` можно избавиться от `margin-top: 23px;` - браузер сам поставит текст вертикально в центре относительно высоты Вашего меню.
- лого у вас сделано как `background-image` зачем-то. Кажется нет необходимости... ну ладно. Однако, если уж сделали его фоном, не забудьте сделать `background-repeat: no-repeat;`
- для того, чтобы в моем сниппете код нормально показывался, мне пришлось заменить все ваши `col-XX-X` классы. Вы можете использовать свои.

Вобщем, думаю, что если Вы возьмете предложенный мною подход за основу, то сможете исправить свое меню на более подвластный Вам и понятный бразуерам вариант...

Comment: а как тогда прописать лого?

Comment: Ну его же можно как обычную картинку вставить. `div > a > img`